# My cat does not play with me after giving birth

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, breeding

My cat had 3 kittens 2 months ago.

Before she was pregnant, she used to play with me all the time, but now she doesn't. Why do you think she no longer plays with me?

Comment: Are the kittens she had still present?

Answer (score 4):

**You can't force cats to do anything.**

Cats, unlike dogs, only do the things they like to do.

Cats go through some changes in their character as they grow up. These changes occur when they go into puberty, when they are neutered or when they give birth. These changes are completely normal, humans go through such phases as well. So, do not expect your cat to behave in the same way all her life.

But do not think that it is permanent. Maybe not as much as she used to, but I am sure that your cat will start play with you again.

The important things for you are:

- **Respect her wishes.**
- **Do not force your cat to play with you.** You will only make her avoid you.
- **Reward her with treats if she plays with you when you throw her toys or strings.** But do not use treats too much. They might hurt her tummy.

I am sure after her kittens grow up, maybe in a month or two, she will start moving back to her old routine. Then she will spend more time with you.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening because of her pregnancy with her kittens. If the kittens are still present with her, the mother cat will try to protect them. Instinctively, mother cats know that it’s their number one job to raise and protect their young. She may be in a grouchy mood because of the stress and tiredness of raising her young.